# How can I programmatically disable Gutenberg query block patterns?

Tags: block-editor

I have this function in my theme's functions.php file:

```
remove_theme_support( 'core-block-patterns' );
```

which works great but does not remove the Query patterns.  How can I include those to be removed in this function?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/27822

Comment: @jdm2112 I'm not seeing anything in that pull request that allows me to hide the Query patterns

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My fix for this issue is editing the Gutenberg plugin and removing the blocks there.  I have not found a way to cleanly remove them through functions.php.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable all "experimental block patterns" including the query block patterns by adding a filter:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
  add_filter(
    'block_editor_settings_all',
    function ($editor_settings) {
      $editor_settings['__experimentalBlockPatterns'] = [];
      return $editor_settings;
    }
  );
});
```

You can see all editor settings (that you could disable with this filter) in this comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/block_editor_settings_all/#comment-5661